# How to install rpm in opt directory

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I have created rpm for one of the package. I want to install that rpm in opt directory but by default it gets installed in root directory. I have tried using Prefix in spec file but it's not working.
I have tried rpm -ivh --prefix=/opt as well but rpm always gets installed in root directory.
rpm is relocatable.

The output of `rpm -qpi abc.rpm`:

```
Name        : abc
Version     : 1.4
Release     : 0
Architecture: x86_64
Install Date: (not installed)
Group       : Applications/Multimedia
Size        : 39054113
License     : GPL
Signature   : (none)
Source RPM  : abc.rpm
Build Date  : Wednesday 05 August 2020 09:10:51 PM IST
Build Host  : localhost
Relocations : /usr 
Packager    : 
Summary     : Xiph Streaming media server that supports multiple formats.
Description :
```

SPEC file for RPM:

```
Name:           abc
Version:        1.4
Release:        0
Summary:        
Group:          
License:        
Source:         %{name}.tar.gz
Prefix:         %{_prefix}
Packager:        xyz
BuildRoot:      %{_tmppath}/%{name}-root
%description
 rpm
%Prefix /opt
%prep
rm -rf %{_topdir}/BUILD/*
%setup -n abc

%build

%install
mkdir -p -m0755 %{buildroot}/
cp -r %{_builddir}/%{name} %{buildroot}/

%clean
#rm -rf %{buildroot}
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT

%files
%defattr(-,root,root)
/abc/daemon
/abc/proxy
/abc/service-files
/abc/pip-selfcheck.json
/abc/requirements.txt
/abc/README.md
/abc/.git
/abc/venv.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 2):

correct your spec file like this:

```
Prefix: /opt
...
%install
mkdir -p -m0755 %{buildroot}/
cp -r %{_builddir}/%{name} %{buildroot}/opt/

%files
%defattr(-,root,root)
/opt/abc/daemon
```

further info: http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-reloc-prefix-tag.html